# Bash String removal on multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, string, bash

I've got two arrays in my bash, each containing files. In my loop, sometimes a file gets deleted. Whenever that happens, one of the arrays shows the old state, the other one shows the new state. How do I manage to show the difference between them, e. g. which file exactly got deleted? By the way, there is no other way to find out.

Here's an example:

```
arr_a=( file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt )
arr_b=( file1.txt file3.txt )

#Now the output should be file2.txt
```

I imagined something lile `echo ${arr_a[@]#arr_b[@]}`, but this didn't work. (This results in arr_a being output entirely.)

Comment: Are the arrays always in the same sequence with only elements deleted, or can elements also be added?

Comment: I think you might have to resort to nested for loops on this one.

Comment: No addition, only deletion, just like in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is a bit complicated but will work in the case the arrays don't maintain correlativity. It sorts all elements of the larger array to correlate to those in the shorter array, and then prints the remaining elements in the larger array (it works on copies of the arrays). Not fully tested:

```
#!/bin/bash
arr_a=( file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt )
arr_b=( file1.txt file3.txt )

sortarr() {
    local sorted=( ${!1} ) sortby=( ${!2} )
    local length=${#sorted[@]} i=${#sortby} matches
    while (( i-- )); do
        [[ ! "${sorted[@]}" =~ ${sortby[$i]} ]] && continue
        sorted=( ${sorted[@]//$BASH_REMATCH/} )
        printf -v matches '%*s' $(( $length - ${#sorted[@]} ))
        sorted=( ${matches// /$BASH_REMATCH }${sorted[@]} )
    done
    for (( i=${#sortby[@]}; i<${#sorted[@]}; i++ )); do
        echo ${sorted[$i]}
    done
}

if (( ${#arr_a[@]} > ${#arr_b[@]} )); then
    sortarr arr_a[@] arr_b[@]
else
    sortarr arr_b[@] arr_a[@]
fi
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. I'll modify this further for my needs. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

@David: What you basically need is the difference between two sets. This can be done much more easily using a little bit of python as shown in Method-0 below. Method-1 and 2 are just two variations using Bash indexed and sparse array. Output for each of the following methods is `file2.txt`

**Method-0:**

```
#!/bin/bash

arr_a=( file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt )
arr_b=( file1.txt file3.txt )

echo -e "${arr_a[@]} \n ${arr_b[@]}" | python -c '\
    a=set(raw_input().strip().split());\
    b=set(raw_input().strip().split());\
    (x,y)=(a,b) if len(a)>len(b) else (b,a);\
    print "".join(list(x-y));'
```

**Method-1:**

```
#!/bin/bash

arr_a=( file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt )
arr_b=( file1.txt file3.txt )
i=0

for a in ${arr_a[@]}
do
    AinB=0
    for b in ${arr_b[@]}
    do
        if [[ $a == $b ]]
        then
            AinB=1
        fi
    done

    if [[ AinB -eq 0 ]]
    then
        arr_c[$((i++))]=$a
    fi
done

echo ${arr_c[@]}
```

**Method-2:**

```
#!/bin/bash

arr_a="file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt"
arr_b="file1.txt file3.txt"
arr_c=""

for a in $arr_a
do
    isPresentInB=0
    for b in $arr_b
    do
        if [[ $a == $b ]]
        then
            isPresentInB=1
            break
        fi
    done

    if [[ $isPresentInB -eq 0 ]]
    then
        arr_c="$arr_c $a"
    fi
done

echo $arr_c
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
arr_a=(file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt)
arr_b=(file1.txt file3.txt)
answer=$(comm -3 <(printf "%s\n" "${arr_a[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${arr_b[@]}")
echo "$answer"
file2.txt
```

Perhaps it would be wise to be a little more robust:

```
arr_answer=($(comm -3 <(printf "%s\n" "${arr_a[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${arr_b[@]}") | paste -sd' '))
((${#arr_answer[@]}==1)) && echo "$arr_answer" || echo "oops! wrong answer"
```